# Deserialzing Xml into List<T> with C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am having trouble deserializing xml into a class that contains a list. Everything builds fine in the object until it gets to the list. I have read all the posts here and tried pretty much everything but it still seems to crap out.

XML: ("text.xml")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<example>
   <id>123456</id>
      <messages>
         <message>
            <words>Hello</words>
         </message>
         <message>
            <words>world</words>
         </message>
      </messages>
</example>
```

Code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args) {
     try {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));


        XmlDocument objDoc = new XmlDocument();
        objDoc.Load("test.xml");

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(objDoc.OuterXml));

        Example example;

        example = (Example)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Console.WriteLine(example.Id.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(example.Messages.Count.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(example.Messages[0].Words);
     }
     catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
     }
     Console.ReadLine();

  }

  [XmlRoot("example")]
  public class Example {
     [XmlElement("id")]
     public int Id {
        get {
           return id;
        }
        set {
           id = value;
        }
     }
     private int id;

     [XmlElement("messages")]
     public List<Message> Messages {
        get {
           return messages;
        }
        set {
           messages = value;
        }
     }
     private List<Message> messages;
  }

  [XmlRoot("message")]
  public class Message {
     [XmlElement("words")]
     public string Words {
        get {
           return words;
        }
        set {
           words = value;
        }
     }
     private string words;
  }
```

Output:

123456

1

Am I missing at tag somewhere that the Serializer needs? Or is what I'm trying to accomplish not possible? Any pointers or shove in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

Notice the definition of XmlArray and XmlArraItem.  I'm sure someone else will have a better way but this will get it working.  Also, you should use the 'using' statement to dispose of the xml reader.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Example));

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
            {

                Example example = (Example)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                Console.WriteLine(example.Id.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(example.Messages.Count.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(example.Messages[0].Words);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    [XmlRoot("example")]
    public class Example
    {
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                id = value;
            }
        }
        private int id;

        [XmlArray("messages")]
        [XmlArrayItem("message", typeof(Message))]
        public List<Message> Messages
        {
            get
            {
                return messages;
            }
            set
            {
                messages = value;
            }
        }
        private List<Message> messages;
    }

    [XmlRoot("message")]
    public class Message
    {
        [XmlElement("words")]
        public string Words { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. This sounds familiar now but couldn't find it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I could see why you're confused.  You're object structure doesn't match your XML though.  You have a single `messages` node, and that node contains the list.  So the structure really looks like:

```
[XmlRoot("example")]
public class Example
{
     [XmlElement("id")]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("messages")]
     public Messages Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Messages
{
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public List<Message> Message { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    [XmlElement("words")]
    public string Words { get; set; }
}
```

runningg your code against that structure gets you the right output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  [XmlRoot("example")]
  public class Example {
     [XmlElement("id")]
     public int Id { get; set;}

     [XmlElement("messages")]
     public Message messages {get; set;}
  }
  [XmlRoot("messages")]
  public class Messages {
     [XmlElement("message")]
     public List<Message> message { get; set;}

  }
  [XmlRoot("message")]
  public class Message {
     [XmlElement("words")]
     public string Words { get; set;}

  }​
```